# Как изменить цвет фона TextBox когда он выбран для ввода?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, .net-4.8

Я пишу кастомный стиль для TextBox с переопределением ControlTemplate. Мне необходимо, чтобы цвет фона текстового поля изменялся при наведении на него курсора и при установке каретки. Триггеры для свойств `IsMouseOver` и `IsFocused` работают, а вот как поймать установку каретки - не пойму.

Пробовал использовать свойство `IsKeyboardFocused`, но не срабатывало.

### Код XAML стиля

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
                             Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                             Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                             Background="#333337"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Auto"
                             TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                             TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="#3f3f46" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="#3f3f46" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="#3f3f46" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: что значит `при установке каретки` и чем оно отличается от получения фокуса? Вы разве можете установить каретку, не установмв фокус при этом?

Comment: Странный у вас стиль, который в себя помещает текст бокс, вместо переопределения стилей...

Comment: Вы меняете вид текстбокса, используя в нем текстбокс. Не кажется странным? Посмотрите например в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates), там нету `TextBox`'а, а есть некий элемент, имя которого `PART_ContentHost`. Если взять ваш стиль и немного переделать, то будет правильней наверно [так](https://pastebin.com/VxFNt2Hs). Как видите, цвет у нас общий, мы не обращаемся к элементу по имени, за отображения текста у нас отвечает `ScrollViewer` (который кстати отлично обрабатывает `IsKeyboardFocused`).